# Firebird select data from table a or b

Tags: firebird

I am working on a project which shows HTML documents constructed from a Firebird database. In separate files, I have SQL queries. How can I get data from table a, or b in this case?

For example:

```
Declare varID int = __docid__;

select fielda, fieldb AS fieldbv from
if(varID = 10) then tableA;
else tableB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use stored procedure with parameter `varId`.
In this procedure get the values from table A and B, check the parameter  and return desired result. Something like:

```
if (:varId = 10) then
   Select fieldA from tableA where ... into :OutParam;
else
   Select fieldB from tableB where ...into :OutParam;
Suspend;
```

From your project just call this procedure with param `varId`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select iif(varID = 10 ,fielda, fieldb) AS Value from  then tableA left 
join tableB on tableA.id=tableB.id
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on [so]. Please explain a bit what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: i just to to show in our condition if varid =10 in simple query. Not in procedure..

Comment: Nice idea, but could cause serious performance hit if tables are big (where did you take `id` field from?)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXECUTE STATEMENT` to run fully dynamic queries. But if you have only 2 choices, Val's answer is good enough.