# Firebird If-Else with Queries

Tags: sql, firebird

I have the following problem: 
I'd like to use a specific query depending what number a user has set in Firebird SQL, so in pseudo code:

```
IF (TABLENAME.USERFLAG <> 5 WHERE TABLENAME.USER = 15555) THEN
EXECUTE QUERY 1
ELSE
EXECUTE QUERY 2
```

The problem is, that does not seem to work. What could I do to get it working?

Comment: Your `if` statement is kind of weird so I'm not sure what it means but it seems to me that your logic should be in the client, ie the client desides which query to execute.

Comment: You can't use an `IF` statement in SQL. You would need to put this into a stored procedure

Comment: You may use a stored procedure ,something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802353/firebird-select-data-from-table-a-or-b/31802962#31802962

Comment: Your requirements aren't really clear (eg how and where has the user set those values). An option is a stored procedure or an [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html) (which is like an anonymous stored procedure). But without more clarification that is hard to tell. It might be better to solve this in the application itself.